# Loading package RTGC

Tags: packages

I am facing a problem in loading the package RTGC. I want to load the file EDCRTGC.m. But when I am giving the command

> EDCRTGCcode.m

it shows the following error

> SetDelayed: Tag Classify in Classify[x_] is Protected.

What should I do?

Comment: You could try to go into the package and change each occurence of `Classify` to `classify`, `RTGC Classify` or any other symbol that is not built-in.

Comment: Inside the package Classify seems like a function acting on some argument. Is this the only way?

Comment: Quite likely. The point is that `Classify` has become a built-in symbol in newer versions of Mathematica so that must not be overwritten by the package.

Comment: You can also try to evaluate `Unprotect[Classify];ClearAll[Classify];` before loading the package.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work quite well now.

Comment: It should be enough to change first occurrence of `Classify` symbol in package file to ``EDCRTGC`Classify`` (or whatever context this package is using). You'll get shadowing warning, and context-free `Classify` symbol will be red, but there's nothing wrong with that. ``EDCRTGC`Classify`` and ``System`Classify`` will be separate symbols with separate definitions living in separate contexts not interfering with each other. If you don't want to edit package file, evaluation of ``EDCRTGC`Classify`` symbol, before loading the package, should also do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Turning a comment into an answer*

You can also try to evaluate `Unprotect[Classify];ClearAll[Classify];` before loading the package.

Comment: Might also be worth noting how dangerous this is if they ever want to use a `Classifier`